# JSON preview is not working in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: php, json, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have just updated my chrome to `Version 61.0.3163.100` and it stopped formatting JSON data in network preview tab in Dev tools.

Chrome is now showing plain string for JSON.

[image]

So is this a bug in new version or have they added some configuration for it which is turned off?

Comment: @wOxxOm No, that also have the same issue.

Comment: https://crbug.com/767393

Comment: @ParantapParashar - we are (unfortunately) seeing the same problem after the Chrome update to Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).  We haven't found any settings that would restore tree functionality in the Preview tab of Dev Tools.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the link. Seems that they have fixed the issue and beta is launched. A stable fix will be available soon then.

Comment: @cre8value Please refer to the link provided in comments. They have launched a beta fix. You can use it for now and a stable release should be  coming soon.

Comment: This is a bug fixed in Canary version.

Comment: @PetrPeller Yes. I just figured that out. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the issue is finally fixed on new Chrome update.

I am using Chrome `v62.0.3202.94` right now.

Answer (score 3):

After much research, it looks like this was a new feature added to Chrome Dev Tools.

You can get around it on your own development server by making sure your Content Type on your Response Headers is set to 'application/json':

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

This fixed the problem for me.

See more here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/zaphAp4r8zo

Comment: Yes. But till the v60 it supported for text/html as well. And, in current scenario we are only able to work with APIs, so server side changes are not in our scope. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for me only work setting in php response:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```